# Two way databinding for WinForms ComboBox with separate source for Items and SelectedItem

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I hope my title makes sense. I want to do the following:

1. Bind ComboBox Items to a list
2. Bind the SelectedItem to a property (separate from the list)
3. Update the SelectedItem of the ComboBox once something in the object changes (for example, once the property that is bound to SelectedItem changes programatically, the SelectedItem of the ComboBox also changes accordingly)

I have already achieved to do the first two things but I am stuck on point 3. The databinding only works one-way. Meaning, when I select a new Item from the ComboBox, the object in code behind changes accordingly. But if I change the object in code behind or if it has an initial value, the SelectedItem of the ComboBox is not updated/preselected.

```
cbErledigungsArt.DataSource = _erledigungsArten.ToArray()
cbErledigungsArt.DisplayMember = "Beschreibung"
cbErledigungsArt.ValueMember = "ID"

cbErledigungsArt.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", _feststellung, "ErledigungsArt")
```

Festellung is a custom type:

```
Public Class FeststellungDTO
    Public Property Jahr() As Integer
    Public Property ErledigungsArt() As ErledigungsArtDTO
End Class
```

Erledigungsart is the property that is bound to the ComboBox

```
Public Class ErledigungsArtDTO
    Public Property ID() As Integer
    Public Property Beschreibung() As String
End Class
```

I want to be able to say, for example:

```
Dim _feststellung As New FeststellungDTO() With {
    .Jahr = 2015,
    .ErledigungsArt = New ErledigungsArtDTO() With {.ID = 0, .Beschreibung = "Bla"}
}
Dim _erledigungsArten As New List(Of ErledigungsArtDTO)(
    {
        New ErledigungsArtDTO() With {.ID = 0, .Beschreibung = "Bla"},
        New ErledigungsArtDTO() With {.ID = 1, .Beschreibung = "Blu"}
    }
)
cbErledigungsArt.DataSource = _erledigungsArten.ToArray()
cbErledigungsArt.DisplayMember = "Beschreibung"
cbErledigungsArt.ValueMember = "ID"

cbErledigungsArt.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", _feststellung, "ErledigungsArt")

'SelectedItem will become "Bla"

_feststellung.ErledigungsArt = New ErledigungsArtDTO() With {.ID = 1, .Beschreibung = "Blu"}

'SelectedItem will become "Blu"

'User now selects "Bla" from the ComboBox and the value of _festellung.ErledigungsArt will change accordingly
```

Is this possible?

Comment: See if implementing INotifyPropertyChanged might help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface

Comment: I think WPF has 2-way binding.

Comment: Generally speaking, you bind the `SelectedValue` of the `ComboBox` in this scenario.  It's usually done to handle a foreign key situation.  For instance, the `DataSource` for the `ComboBox` is a parent `DataTable` and the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` are "ParentName" and "ParentId" respectively, then the `SelectedValue` is bound to the "ParentId" column of a child `DataTable`.  Obviously the types can be different but the principle remains the same.